# Android Jetpack Compose call view-model function only once

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

There is a screen level composable under an activity. When user is navigated to that screen, I'm using a `LaunchedEffect(Unit) {}` to call view-model function which does some work. Now, this works fine until the device rotates or any configuration change occurs. After rotation or so, `LaunchedEffect(Unit) {}` is executed again which is not desirable.

I know I can use a flag in the view-model or in the composable function itself to prevent doing the work again. But, writing here to find if there is any ideal solution to this problem as this seems to be a common problem in Jetpack Compose.

PS: The function needs to be in the screen level view-model only and not at activity-level. Also, cannot use `init` of view-model as the function which the screen-level composable is calling needs some data as it's parameters.

Comment: If this function needs to be executed only once for the screen, you can put it in `init` block of the view model

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain what this function does, in that case somebody might come up with something useful

Comment: Actually, in my case I cannot use `init` of view-model because the view-model needs some input which the screen-level composable will provide while calling the function from the view-model. I'll update the question to mention the same.

Comment: You should take care of this in your `ViewModel`. Your `ViewModel` should return cached data when the user rotates their screen, this caching mechanism is something you'll have to implement yourself. If you can show how your viewmodel function looks like, perhaps you would get some help on how to do this

Comment: @Rafsanjani this seems to be a solution here. To have some caching in the view-model

Comment: @dev.tejasb I've posted a hypothetical answer with `ViewModel` caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement some basic caching in your `ViewModel`. Here is a hypothetical example of where the `ViewModel` will return cached data to subscribers during configuration changes.

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    sealed interface MainViewState {
        data object Content : MainViewState
        data object Loading : MainViewState
        data class Error(val error: Throwable) : MainViewState
    }

    private val _viewState: MutableStateFlow<MainViewState> =
        MutableStateFlow(MainViewState.Loading)

    val viewState = _viewState.asStateFlow()

    init {
       loadData()
    }

    private fun loadData() = viewModelScope.launch {
        // We have cached data, do nothing, StateFlow will re-emit latest state to new subscribers
        if (_viewState.value == MainViewState.Content) {
            return@launch
        }

        _viewState.update {
            MainViewState.Loading
        }

        // Load some data and return MainViewState.Content or MainViewState.Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LaunchedEffect` will run every time it recomposes.  You can use `rememberSaveable` for this and add a flag to not run the code again.  Actually, it would be more accurate to do this in a `viewModel`, but since you specifically want it this way, you can look at this example.

```
var workCompleted by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        if (!workCompleted) {
            // your work
            workCompleted = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Faruk Karaca but, this is something I can already implement. I'm looking if there is any better solution without using any flag. I've also updated the question to clarify.

Comment: No problem! However, there is a situation here. Even if you find a function and use it, the function will persist in memory, remembering whether it has been executed before and operating accordingly. In other words, any one-time operation you desire will only run after checking a flag or counter. We are adhering to the same logic in every instance. Unfortunately, we cannot avoid this situation because we are unable to prevent it from recomposing. This is how the logic operates due to the nature of Compose. In such cases, the most advisable approach is to store it in a viewModel.

Comment: I am following this question. If anyone offers a different solution, I would be grateful.